# Is it necessary to dispose a DataTable that fails to get filled?

Tags: .net, datatable, dispose

I have a function that fills a `DataTable` using a `SqlDataAdapter`

```
// ...
using (SqlDataAdapter dataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(command))
    try
    {
        dataAdapter.Fill(dataTable);
    }
    catch
    {
        dataTable.Dispose();
        dataTable = null;
    }
```

Now, I dislike cargo-cult programming, so I would rather not have a `try`-`catch` block if it is unnecessary. Is it necessary to `Dispose` a `DataTable` that fails to get filled?

Comment: How does your question have anything to do with the question's title?

Comment: @Marc B: Sorry, I accidentally copied the title from another question. I like opening several StackOverflow question pages, just in case.

Comment: Great, cargo-cult is banging on the door loudly.  DataTable doesn't implement Dispose().  No point, it is just a bag of bytes.  It inherits it from MarshalByValueComponent.  Which only does something semi-interesting (not really) when you used the data designer, the "component" part.  If you didn't then Dispose() does nothing at all.  I can't post this as an answer of course.

Comment: @Hans Passant: I'll upvote it anyway! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, calling `Dispose` is not required. Doing so will not deallocate the memory that has been used for the object, and the GC will pick it up at a later point even if you don't call `Dispose`. You can read more about this [here](http://www.developerdotstar.com/community/node/247).

Comment: Awesome answer! It would be nice if the MSDN documentation contained this information.

Answer (score 1):

Since the try block has failed calling Dispose on the object is not necessary

Answer (score 1):

If *your code* creates an object of a particular *explicit* concrete type which is documented as implementing IDisposable.Dispose as a no-op, then one may safely do without calling Dispose directly or indirectly.  If Dispose really does nothing, then disposing or not disposing won't affect anything.

On the other hand, if your code uses something like a factory method to create an object of an inheritable type which implements IDisposable, or if your code is given ownership of such an object, then you should dispose it.  Even if you're expecting to get an object of a class which doesn't need to be Disposed, there's no way to be sure your class won't instead receive a derived type which does need to be Disposed.  Note that in general, calling Dispose on a class which implements IDispsoable.Dispose as a no-op will be very quick; it's often more efficient for classes which may or may not need IDisposable to implement Dispose as a no-op, and have users of the class call Dispose unconditionally, than to require that a user of the class test whether an object is IDisposable, and Dispose it if so.